# What should my API endpoint look like in production?

Tags: docker, web-deployment

I have this web app. Frontend is written with VueJS, backend with Django rest framework, and I am using MongoDB with docker volumes.

On the Home page of my web app, Frontend sends a GET request to backend on `/api/skills` endpoint.

When I handle things locally, everything is fine. I dockerize the frontend, backend, MongoDB and they all talk to each other in the same Docker network.

[image]

This is looking nice on local development. The part that does the fetching looks like this.

```js
fetchSkillData: function () {
      const localUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/skills";
      axios
        .get(localUrl)
        .then((values) => {
          values.data.forEach((data) => {
            this.technologies.push(data);
            this.hideSpinner();
          });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
      this.hideSpinner();
    }
```

I am not getting a CORS issue or anything else.

However, on production, I have some issues.

This is the Dockerfile for frontend:

```
# build stage
FROM node:13-alpine as build-stage
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY ./frontend /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save ant-design-vue
RUN npm install --save mavon-editor
RUN npm install --save axios
RUN npm install --save raw-loader

RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /home/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is the Dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM python:alpine

ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME=admin \
    MONGO_DB_PWD=password
    
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY requirements.txt /home/app

# install requirements
RUN pip3 install -r /home/app/requirements.txt

COPY ./azure_website_backend /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python","manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000","--settings=azure_website_backend.settings"]
```

And this is the app.yml file for Docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  vue-frontend:
    image: burakhanaksoy/vue-frontend:1.0
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  django-backend:
    image: burakhanaksoy/django-backend:1.0
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

When I deploy it on Azure, frontend cannot talk to backend, the same api endpoint has this issue now

[image]

I added a CORS middleware on django. So I don't think this issue is related to CORS.

I think the issue stems from me still sending a request to `0.0.0.0`. Probably the IP is dynamically changing but I am still sending a request to `0.0.0.0`. But I don't know how to fix this. I looked lots and lots of documents and others' questions but I am very novice on deployment so I couldn't figure it out. I appreciate any help.

Also, I know that I shouldn't send to `0.0.0.0` because Azure logs always show a different host port everytime I deploy.

[image]

---

**Update**

I am trying to integrate nginx with vuejs to make use of `proxy_pass`.

This is how my dockerfile looks like for Vue

```
# build stage
FROM node:13-alpine as build-stage
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY . /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save ant-design-vue
RUN npm install --save mavon-editor
RUN npm install --save axios
RUN npm install --save raw-loader

RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /home/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And this is `nginx.conf`:

```
events { }
http{
  server {
      listen       80;
      server_name  localhost;

      location / {
          root     path/to/vue.js/Project;
          index    index.html index.htm;
          include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
      }
  }
}
```

When I build image and run this container. I get 500 Internal Server Error from nginx. This means I integrated nginx but did not configured it properly?

This is what I get

[image]

---

**Update 2**

Nginx logs the following error on Docker Desktop

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh

/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up

2021/11/13 10:38:20 [error] 32#32: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"

2021/11/13 10:38:20 [error] 32#32: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"

2021/11/13 10:39:11 [error] 32#32: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"

2021/11/13 10:39:13 [error] 24#24: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"

2021/11/13 10:39:13 [error] 24#24: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"

2021/11/13 10:40:29 [error] 25#25: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "0.0.0.0:8080"

2021/11/13 10:40:29 [error] 25#25: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/favicon.ico", host: "0.0.0.0:8080", referrer: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/"
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it usually only makes sense to use it when you're _listening_ for connections, but not when you're making outbound connections.  If the frontend serves the React application as static files and `proxy_pass /api ...` to the back-end container, can you connect to `/api/skills`, without a hostname?

Comment: How can I use the proxy_pass ? I am updating my question for latest news can you please check @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fetchSkillData: function () {
    const localUrl = "/api/skills";
    axios
        .get(localUrl)
        .then((values) => {
          values.data.forEach((data) => {
            this.technologies.push(data);
            this.hideSpinner();
          });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
      this.hideSpinner();
    }
```

Or this:

```
async fetchSkillData(){
   try {
     const resp = await axios.get('/api/skills');
     console.log(resp.data);
   } catch (err) {
     // Handle Error Here
     console.error(err);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy on `Azure` you will have another hostname then when you deploy locally. Appearently you port to 0.0.0.0 locally, but when you deploy a docker container on Azure it will not do anything unless you also configured a Virtual Machine or [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/.). That depends on your setup.

## Virtual machines

Your Virtual Machine will have a [custom hostname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/cloudinit-update-vm-hostname) which will be the same as your Virtual Machine.

## AKS

If you configured AKS you must create a deployment where you link to your docker container to spin up some replica's. More about deployments on [K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). Once you did a deployment you need a service to expose your deployment outside the cluster. You can use a variety of services, but usually yoiu have to configure `ClusterIP` and [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). The hostname of your deployment equals the`metdata.name`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-custom-host-name
```

## Vue app

To use environment variables with Vue3 you have to pass those before you build your front-end. Those environment variables will be interpolated in your code via: `process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL`. For Vue3 you must prefix environment variables with `VUE_APP_` or use a `.env` file. So add the following env before you run your build script in the pipeline:

```
 VUE_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL=http://[BACKEND_HOST]:8000 npm run build
```

## Docker compose

In `docker-compose` you have to set the env var as well and rebuild the application using `docker-compose up` or `docker compose up`. Please note the `hostname` in docker compose is the name of your service.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  vue-frontend:
    image: burakhanaksoy/vue-frontend:1.0
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - VUE_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL=django-backend:8000

  django-backend:
    image: burakhanaksoy/django-backend:1.0
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```